# nextElementSibling not working, unexpected behavior with objects or class javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having an unexpected behavior using nextElementSibling property. the unexpected behavior only happens when I use the object document and his methods in another object attributes.

I'm doing a slider the goal is passing slides removing some class name from the current element add to the next element the same class name removed before, the problem is that I can remove from the first element and add to the second element but than stops doing it to the next elements, allways stop at the second element, and it only happens when I'm adding the document object to an attribute of an object.

My code

```js
const Slider = {
    slides: document.querySelectorAll('.slide'),
    currentSlide: document.querySelector('.current-slide'),
    next: document.getElementById("next"),
    nextSlide: function () {
        this.currentSlide.classList.remove("current-slide");
        if (this.currentSlide.nextElementSibling) {
            this.currentSlide.nextElementSibling.classList.add('current-slide');
        } else {
            this.slides[0].classList.add('current-slide');
        }
    },
    onClick: function () {
        console.log()
        this.next.addEventListener('click', event => {
            console.log('CLICK');
            this.nextSlide();
        });

    }
}

Slider.onClick();
```

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: aqua;
}

/* SLIDE AND ALL CONTENT */

.slide {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4 ease-in-out;
}

.slide.current-slide {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slide .slide-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: -2500px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(136, 18, 18, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 35px;
}

.slide.current-slide .slide-content {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(2500px);
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0.2s;
}



.slide-content h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron:400,500,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
<main class="slider">
    <section class="slide current-slide">
      <div class="slide-content">
        <h1>Slide1</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="slide">
      <div class="slide-content">
        <h1>Slide2</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="slide">
      <div class="slide-content">
        <h1>Slide3</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="slide">
      <div class="slide-content">
        <h1>Slide4</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <div class="buttons-next-prev">
    <button id="next">
     click
    </button>
  </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are not updating `this.currentSlide` anywhere. (The result of `querySelector` is _not_ “live”, as node lists returned by f.e. `getElementsByClassName` would be.)

Comment: The content of `currentSlide` won't change just because you add the class to a different element.

Comment: Thank you @misorude you were right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the properties of `Slider` (`slides` and `currentSlide`) are not updated automatically when you have modified the DOM elements. They have the state when `querySelectorAll` was executed, so you have to update them manually or query them again.

To give you an idea:

```
getCurrentSlide: function() {
  this.currentSlide = document.querySelector(".current-slide");
},
nextSlide: function() {
  this.currentSlide.classList.remove("current-slide");
  if (this.currentSlide.nextElementSibling) {
    this.currentSlide.nextElementSibling.classList.add("current-slide");
  } else {
    this.slides[0].classList.add("current-slide");
  }
  this.getCurrentSlide(); // update currentSlide in Slider
},
```

The `slides` object still represents the initial content though.

Comment: Yup that worked pretty well, never cross to my mind that the the properties would never be updated, thank you @wiesson...